# Pre-allocate varbinary(max) without actually sending null data to the SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, varbinary

I'm storing data in a varbinary(max) column and, for client performance reasons, chunking writes through the ".WRITE()" function using SQL Server 2005. This works great but, due to the side effects, I want to avoid the varbinary column dynamically sizing during each append.

What I'd like to do is optimize this by pre-allocating the varbinary column to the size I want. For example if I'm going to drop 2MB into the column I would like to 'allocate' the column first, then .WRITE the real data using offset/length parameters.

Is there anything in SQL that can help me here? Obviously I don't want to send a null byte array to the SQL server, as this would partially defeat the purpose of the .WRITE optimization.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  It sounds like you need a fixed allocation, but are using a variable allocation.  Why use varbinary at all if you want a fixed allocation?

Comment: I need variable (per row) allocation, but I know the full size for the column when I start updating a particular row. Rather than resizing the column N*Buffer times, I'd like to size it once, then copy my chunks in the right spot. That way I can avoid the resizing/moving operations on the variable field while I'm chunking in the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a (MAX) data type, then anything above 8K goes into row overflow storage, not the in-page storage. So you just need to put in enough data to get it up to the 8K for the row, making that take up the in-page allocation for the row, and the rest goes into row-overflow storage anyway. There's some more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189087.aspx).

If you want to pre-allocate everything, including the row overflow data, you can use something akin to (example does 10000 bytes):

```
SELECT CONVERT([varbinary](MAX), REPLICATE(CONVERT(varchar(MAX), '0'), 10000))
```

Comment: This seems like it'll work well but I've never used REPLICATE with a large amount of data. Do you know how it performs when you're replicating to 1MB or more?

Comment: No, I haven't really done a lot of testing with it, to be honest, but it's the only way I can see to simply achieve what you need...

Answer (score 1):

First of all kudos to the answer provided - this was a great help!  However, there is one slight change that you may want to consider.  The code above actually allocates the varbinary field with a converted zero character (hex code 0x30).  This may not be what you actually want, particularly if you want to perform binary operations on the field later.  What I think is more useful is to allocate the field with a NUL value (hex code 0x00) so that all the bits are turned off by default.  To do this, simply make the following correction:

`SELECT CONVERT([varbinary](MAX), REPLICATE(CONVERT(varchar(MAX), CHAR(0)), 10000))`