# Expand data in VARBINARY(max) column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, varbinary

What is the best way to expand the data in a `VARBINARY(max)` column, i.e. to set the data to a new length greater than the current length?

```
-----------------------------------------
| current data      |                   |
-----------------------------------------
                    ^                   ^
                    current length      desired new length
```

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523(v=sql.105).aspx), you cannot set `@Offset` to a value greater than the data's length, so `... .WRITE (NULL, newOffset, NULL)` doesn't work. The best solution I was able to come up with is to [Create a binary string of zeros, with variable length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15035145/946850), and append it to the data column. Unfortunately this solution produces server-side hangs (which I haven't been able to analyze yet) in a large installation.

What would be a better way to do this? a Am I missing something obvious?

I need this to provide a storage interface to `VARBINARY(max)` columns. The implementation of this interface is not (yet) aware of the data length, all read/write requests are translated 1:1 to SQL server queries.

Comment: Do you mean you need to append data to the data currently in the field?

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic613703-338-1.aspx#bm613867

Comment: @Oded: Does the drawing clarify matters?

Comment: Not really. If you have new data, append it and overwrite the current values. If you don't have new data, why just append empty data?

Comment: @Oded: Because the client of the storage interface wants it. This is beyond my control, I just need to provide the implementation of this storage interface.

Comment: Fair enough, though I would think that just writing the new values to the field should be enough - let the DB take care of things.

Comment: @Oded: You mean by simply generating a string of zeros and appending it, just the way I am doing? Is there really nothing simpler than that?

Comment: I don't know for certain, but I've never done what you are. Sounds like trying to emulate a binary file interface in the DB (which also sounds like the wrong way about things and the wrong solution for probably that shouldn't be in the database).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30229/discussion-between-krlmlr-and-oded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the number of answers, there is no way other than to [Create a binary string of zeros, with variable length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15035145/946850) and append it in a `.WRITE` query. Others seem to do it similarly: [Pre-allocate varbinary(max) without actually sending null data to the SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2180372/946850).

Posting this just to close the question.